# Website not working on root domain with https

Tags: heroku, deployment, dns, next.js, vercel

I am trying to deploy a NextJS website to Heroku or Vercel and add a domain name to it using https://www.names.co.uk.

Adding the domain works but for some reason I cannot access the website at https://my-website.com, however I can access it with http://my-website.com and https://www.my-website.com. I need it to work for this url 'https://my-website.com' as the website is already ranked in google with this URL. I was wondering if anyone had any idea of how this can be done. Please ask if you need more information.

Apologies if I have posted this in the wrong place.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you create your certificate? They're attached to domains, and if you didn't add the `www` subdomain it won't work there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I actually managed to get this working in Vercel and it was exactly what you said. I had to add the www sub domain and wait a couple hours and now it works. Cheers!